# Can I create a different website and upload my backed-up files there from the previous website?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, backups

Can I create a totally different website (hosting provider + domain name) and upload my backed-up files from my old website if I am missing my database backup?

Comment: You should be able to do this.  Let me know if you need help!

Comment: @JackHacks Thank you for the reply. As I understood from the answer below I will not be able to do so wihtout the database back up ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I assumed you were including the database backup in the backed up files.  If you list the filenames from your backup, we can probably tell you if it includes the database dump.  It depends how you backed up your site.

Comment: Hey ,I think I managed to find my database as well. I have the SQL file, wp-includes,wp-content,wp-admin,wp.config.php, .well-known and a lot of other php file like settings, signup,mail,load,login,cron.

Comment: That's great!  Have you selected a new hosting provider?

Comment: I think I will go with site ground. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your domain has not changed and you only want to have your privious website files on a new host. I hope you have a complete backup including the database as well.
Then you can follow the instructions via the link below (from step 5):
https://wpengine.com/resources/migrate-wordpress-site/
Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. I dont have the database and I would like also change domain name. In ths case is not possible ?

Comment: The new domain name is not big deal. You can use the 'Better search replace' plugin later to  replace the domain name across the content of the website. But as far as I know you need the database to import in new host database. If you have an account in your previous hosting, send a ticket to support team and ask them the latest full backup.